# Incorrect placement of quotation marks

Tags: xetex, listings

I just want to include some sourcecode by using the `listings` package wit XeTeX.

Here is my minimal example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[xetex]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmonofont[Scale=.8]{Inconsolata}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    numbers=left,
    inputencoding=utf8x,
    extendedchars=true,
    showlines=true,
    upquote=true,
    showstringspaces=false
}
\lstdefinelanguage{turtle} {
  morekeywords={@prefix,@base,@forSome,@forAll,@keywords},
%   literate=%
%       *{``}{``}{1}
%       {''}{''}{1}
%       {„}{``}{1}
%       {“}{''}{1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=turtle]
@prefix crm:  <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/> .
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://my.domain/object/1>
  rdf:type
    crm:E22_Man-Made_Object ;
  rdfs:label 
    "„David“ Skulptür …", "This is another ‚test‘ …" ;
  crm:P102_has_title 
    <http://my.domain/title/1> ;
  crm:P108i_was_produced_by
    <http://my.domain/production/1> ;
  crm:P31i_was_modified_by
    <http://my.domain/modification/1> .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This produces te following output:
[image: example listing with wrong quotation marks]

As you can see in line `8` (the last sign at the end) and line `9` (after the first quotation mark; in front of the word `test`) the quotation marks are wrong/incorrect. – `David` should be surrounded by (German) double quotation marks (`„David“`) and `test` with (German) single quotation marks (`‚test‘`).

**→ Does someone know how to fix that/produce that?**

Another problem in line `9` is the display of typographical quotation marks (opening and closing) for the whole string (**"**`„David“ Skulptür …`**"**).
I can only fix this by commenting out `\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}` in the preamble.

**→ Again: Does someone know how to fix that (without disabling `\defaultfontfeatures`)?**

Thanks a lot and best regards!

**PS:**
The disabled `literate` option in the MWE doesn't change anything if is enabled …

Comment: I'm afraid `listings` has problems with Unicode input as interpreted by XeTeX. For the `\defaultfontfeatures` problem, just define the mono font before issuing that declaration. Don't load `xltxtra`, but `fontspec`; the recommendation for the former package has long been obsolete.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for your comment! I now load `fontenc`instead of `xltxtra` and added `\defaultfontfeatures` after my font definitions, but that didn't change anything. :-/ (Maybe now I'm a little bit more future-proof?)

Comment: The second part of the comment is independent from the first, about the problems of `listings` with XeTeX, that remain as you saw.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! – Moving `\defaultfontfeatures` behind `\setmonofont` fixed the 2nd question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `listings` does not work well with UTF-8 input, which means in particular XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. I'm afraid that a very thorough revision of the package would be required for getting it to work with arbitrary UTF-8 input.

However, not all is lost. I downloaded some `pygmentize` lexers from https://github.com/gniezen/n3pygments and installed them (`pygmentize` is required). Then I changed your input in the following way:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=.8]{Inconsolata}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{verbments}

\begin{document}
\begin{pyglist}[language=turtle]
@prefix crm:  <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/> .
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://my.domain/object/1>
  rdf:type
    crm:E22_Man-Made_Object ;
  rdfs:label 
    "„David“ Skulptür …", "This is another ‚test‘ …" ;
  crm:P102_has_title 
    <http://my.domain/title/1> ;
  crm:P108i_was_produced_by
    <http://my.domain/production/1> ;
  crm:P31i_was_modified_by
    <http://my.domain/modification/1> .
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

and compiled the file with

```
xelatex -shell-escape sokai
```

Here's the result, which seems what you were looking for.

[image]

Note that `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` should be issued after defining the monospaced font, if you don't want it to use the standard ligatures.

Also using `xltxtra` is not recommended any more; it's better to call directly `fontspec` as shown. The packages `bold-extra` and `upquote` are not compatible with this setting for XeLaTeX, so I removed them.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! – Your example with the `verbments` package works very well. But I was looking for a solution for the `listings` package, so I can't accept this as an answer … :-/

Also I'm missing many options with the `verbments` package that I'm using wit the `listings` package. But I really like the lexer method used by `pygmentize`!

Thanks for your hints about compatibility and not recommended packages, too. :)

Comment: @sokai As I said, `listings` has problems with UTF-8 encoded files using "arbitrary" characters, because its look-ahead procedures work under the assumption of character codes between 0 and 255.

Comment: O.K. – So the answer of my first question is „There is no (known) solution with the `listings` package. But it can be solved with the `verbments` package.“. – So I will accept your answer. :) (I keep using the `listings` package and try to avoid typographical question marks.)